# Install cocos2D-iPhone manually

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How can I install cocos2D-iPhone manually? I want to include the cocos2D framework into an existing project. Thus, I will not be able to use a cocos2D project template.

Tutorials or web sites would be appreciated (couldn't find any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a tutorial at this [site](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/tutorial-professional-cocos2d-xcode-project-template/)

Comment: because its the right solution for someone that is having the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I would create a new project using the template, and compare it to your own project. For a list of files to compare, and a rough procedure:

1. Copy all cocos2d files from the template over to your project
2. Check Info.plist, and make any necessary changes
3. Modify `main.m` in your target to specify your `AppDelegate` class. For a project called Untitled, you'd use

   ```
   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"UntitledAppDelegate");
   ```
4. Add a target that builds the cocos2d files. This will be a "Static Library" target. use "Get Info" on the template version to figure out exactly what's going on inside.
5. Link required frameworks to your target: CoreGraphics, OpenGLES, QuartzCore, OpenAL, AudioToolbox, libz.dylib, AVFoundation. I think this is all
6. Use "Get Info" on the template target and your target, and make sure you've added the cocos2d library to "Linked Libraries". Also, add "cocos2d libraries" as a linked target.
7. Compare AppDelegate files, and check how the project is instantiated. The main difference is that you won't be using a `Window.xib` file to boot up the project, and will have to manually instantiate the cocos2d stuff. The best way to see the proper startup procedure is to take a look at the template code.

That said, I actually DO use a `UINavigationController` and a `UIViewController` with a nib file for my initial view. To do this, instantiate the `navController` like usual, and use this sort of code to attach it to cocos2d:

```
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:navController.view];
```

That should be everything you need to do for a basic conversion.

If you want access to the project internals, you might use [the method of shared libraries](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/), which will allow you to build a new cocos2d library every time you build your app. The link has a great tutorial on this.

Comment: Excellent answer;  the use of Cocos2d is a lot more than just including the framework and comparing a known working template generated project to the target project is a great way to make this work.  Furthermore, having the templates around makes it trivial to do a throwaway project when trying to figure out how to do something.

Comment: I am trying to make everything as it is in the templates but it is still not working. That's why I am searching for the a guide (I guess it has something to do with the compilation of cocos2d libraries)

Comment: dkk, what errors are you getting? If it's something to do with the libraries: make sure you've created the "cocos2d libraries" target and added it to both the "direct dependencies" and "linked libraries" in your existing target. Can you use http://www.pastie.org/ and show me your errors?

Comment: I get a diveide by 0 error at CCLabelAtlas (Row 75). That doesn't say much about what is linked wrong...

Comment: You're probably missing a png file in there. If you're missing a file, you'll get a divide by zero error, due to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=965. Make sure you've got everything, and comment out as much incidental code as you need to get started.